# Lie bracket in local coordinates. Find the formula $c^{k}$ in terms of $a^{i}$ and $b^{j}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds

[image]

This is from T.U Loring's manifold book. I tried. But I didnt do the question. Please show me how to solve instructively and explicitly. I want to learn this topic. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n), f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ wehave :
$$[X,Y](f)= (X\circ Y)(f)-(Y\circ X)(f)=$$
$$X(\sum b^i\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i})-Y(\sum a^i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i})=$$
$$\sum\left(X(b^i)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}+b^iX(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i})\right)-\sum\left(Y(a^i)\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}+a^iY(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i})\right)=$$
$$\sum\left(a^j\frac{\partial b^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}+b^ia^j\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^j\partial x^i}\right)-\sum\left(b^j\frac{\partial a^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}+a^ib^j\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^j\partial x^i}\right)=$$
$$\sum\left(a^j\frac{\partial b^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}-b^j\frac{\partial a^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^i}\right)=$$
$$\sum \left(a^j\frac{\partial b^i}{\partial x^j}-b^j\frac{\partial a^i}{\partial b^j}\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\right)(f)=\sum c^i\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}(f)$$
Therefore, $$c^i=\sum \left(a^j\frac{\partial b^i}{\partial x^j}-b^j\frac{\partial a^i}{\partial b^j}\right)$$

Comment: you are wonderful. Thank you so much for solution. I am grateful of you.

Answer (score 1):

Since it's a homework problem, I'm not going to give you an explicit solution. However, I will give you a

**Hint/walkthrough**:

Write down $X = \sum a_i\partial_i$ and $Y = \sum b_j\partial_j$. There is only one thing you can do: write down the definition of the Lie bracket, plug in the local coordinate expressions of $X$ and $Y$, and chug-chug-chug.
\begin{align*}[X,Y] &= XY - YX \\
&= \sum a_i\partial_i\sum b_j\partial_j - \sum b_j\partial_j\sum a_i\partial_i \\
\end{align*}
Now distribute, differentiate with the product rule, and use the fact that mixed partial commute. You will end up with a sum of the form
$$\sum \big(\mbox{stuff}\big)\partial_k.$$
The "stuff" are your coefficients $c_k$.

Comment: Well, @Neal I Will write the solution according to whatever I have understood from all you said. And then can you check my solution? Because I dont want to learn false.

Comment: @B11 Do that. Try the problem and edit your attempt into the question and we can take a look at it.

Comment: @B11 It is not correct. You did not use the product rule.

Comment: What is the product rule? @Neal

Comment: PleasE show how to correct my mistake? @Neal

Comment: @B11 The product rule from calculus? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_rule If you don't know the product rule, you probably shouldn't be studying this material.

Comment: Ok I Will edit my mistakes, then can you check again? @Neal

Comment: I really cold not do the product rule on the this example:( @Neal

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8391/discussion-between-neal-and-b11)

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share the reason?